# Create values from matplotlib subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib Figure object which I pass data into that I have created through another process.

```
data_figure = Figure()
data_plot = data_figure.add_subplot(111)
line = data_plot.plot(x_data, y_data)
```

Example graph

[image]

Is there an appropriate way to get data values from the line which I haven't passed in? For example, if I passed in data for x=5 and x=15, could I find the y value for x=10 that the line has drawn?

Comment: You can check out [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d).

Comment: All matplotlib does is draw a straight line between given points, so as @QuangHoang suggests, straight linear interpolation is what you want (if both you axises are linear)

Comment: Thank you both for the reply, that has solved my issue.